# Using time(NULL) on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, posix, bionic

Is there any known problem with using `time(NULL)` on Android?

I tried running the following piece of code:

```
int32_t now1 = time(NULL);
int64_t now1_6 = (int64_t)time(NULL);
int32_t nt = (time_t)-1;
int64_t nt6 = (int64_t)-1;
```

And then log the result using the following format:

```
"Now1 is %d. Now1_6 is %lld. NT is %d. NT6 is %lld.\n", now1, now1_6, nt, nt6
```

This is the output I got:

```
01-05 19:10:15.354: I/SMOS(11738): Now1 is 1533390320. Now1_6 is 6585861276402981128. NT is 0. NT6 is 283493768396.
```

There were other problems as well, such as getting the same time values on different loop iterations.

I encountered these issues on both a virtual and a physical device running Android 4.0.3 (API 15), both of which were configured with the correct time. The output above is from the physical device.

I am led to believe there is a problem with this particular POSIX function in Bionic, but I could not find any reference to such, either online or in the Bionic docs.

Comment: 1533390320 is 0x5B65ADF0, which is a reasonable value for time in seconds (albeit somewhat in the future).  6585861276402981128 is 0x5B65ADF000001908, i.e. you've got the 32-bit time in the high part plus some random gunk in the low part.  283493768396 is 0x42018B9CCC, which looks like a 32-bit pointer in the high plus 0xcc000000 in the low.  Sounds like something isn't passing args around quite right.  Probably not related to time() itself.  Tested with `printf()`, I get `Now1 is 1357606954. Now1_6 is 1357606954. NT is -1. NT6 is -1.`

Comment: You're correct about argument passing - I was mixing log printing functions - `__android_log_print` and `__android_log_vprint` if I remember correctly - so that I was printing garbage to log.  If you put up your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast an `int64_t` into a `long long`, and they might not be equivalent on Android. If you want to print out `int64_t` values using `printf` and `%lld`, either convert the number first to `long long`, or use the correct format modifier:

```
printf("%lld", (long long)now1_6);
```

or

```
printf("%" PRId64, now1_6);
```

For the `time(NULL)` giving false times, try using `gettimeofday` instead:

```
struct timeval tm;
gettimeofday( &tm, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about [these modifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). But my problem was mixing log printing functions - `__android_log_print` and `__android_log_vprint` if I remember correctly - so that I was printing garbage to log.